# In Leaflet.js, how do you grab the right x/y values in order to process them for a tileLayer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have this situation:

```
var layer8 = L.tileLayer('https://blablablabla.com/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=blablabla&ID=3400&STYLES=blablablabla&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG:3067&BBOX={x1},{y1},{x2},{y2}', { x1: 123, y1: 123, x2: 123 + 1024, y2: 123 + 1024, id: 'mapbox.eight', maxNativeZoom: 18, maxZoom: 24 });
```

As you can see, I currently use dummy values for the "boundary box" coordinates. That's because I cannot figure out how to "grab" the "current" x/y values so that I can process them from my sane, local map's coordinate system into the insane, external map's coordinate system.

If I simply use `{x}` and `{y}`, it will get my local map's coordinates which are completely wrong for this external map, and I also would still be unable to specify the "x2" and "y2" values, which are always fixed to 1024 units above x1 and y2.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
...', { x1: convert_coordinate_systems(getCurrentX()), y1: convert_coordinate_systems(getCurrentY()), x2: convert_coordinate_systems(getCurrentX()) + 1024, y2: convert_coordinate_systems(getCurrentY()) + 1024, ...
```

I've been browsing the Leaflet manual and searched for ages to find a solution, but, as always, I find no mention of this whatsoever, as if I'm doing something crazy and wild that nobody has ever needed to do before. Which is almost as frustrating as the problem itself.

Comment: "my sane, local map's coordinate system into the insane, external map's coordinate system". 

What does that mean?

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Look into `L.TileLayer.WMS` instead, including reading https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html

Comment: @IvanSanchez Well, I did, but I did not get any wiser. Still facing the exact same problem.

Comment: I will say I find it strange that you're trying to use bbox on a tilelayer.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @SethLutske The service uses a "bbox". I didn't know there was something other than "tileLayer".

Comment: @IvanSanchez makes a good point.  This is a WMS service.  Leaflet already has a component for that.  Look into that and see if it solves your problem

Comment: @SethLutske Again, I did "look into" it, but I don't get what you mean by it. What exactly am I supposed to do? How does that different function help me?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a function I wrote awhile back to transform the maps bounds into the bbox. It uses EPSG3857, so you might need to adjust that. Based on esri-leaflet source code:

```
/**
 * Calculates the bounding box of the desired image
 * @param llBounds | LatLngBounds of desired image
 * Adjusted from esri-leaflet/src/Layers/RasterLayer.js to not need an L.Map instance
 */
function calculateBbox(latLngBounds: L.LatLngBounds): string {
    const neProjected: Point = L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(
        latLngBounds.getNorthEast()
    );
    const swProjected: Point = L.CRS.EPSG3857.project(
        latLngBounds.getSouthWest()
    );

    // this ensures ne/sw are switched in polar maps where north/top bottom/south is inverted
    var boundsProjected: Bounds = bounds(
        neProjected as any,
        swProjected as any
    );

    return [
        boundsProjected.getBottomLeft().x,
        boundsProjected.getBottomLeft().y,
        boundsProjected.getTopRight().x,
        boundsProjected.getTopRight().y,
    ].join(',');
}
```

Comment: Looks promising, but what am I supposed to send into that function? I've stared at it for a long time now and have no idea. Seems like I'm back at square one again.

Comment: The bounds of the image you want to retrieve.  In my experience, that it used more for raster layers - I'm not sure why you're using it on an L.tileLayer.  But It gives you the bbox of an image raster layer for any given map latLngBounds

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the bounds of the image you want to retrieve".